# How to rerender class component in react js

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-class-based-component

How do I Re render the class component once API call is done. Initially the state is set as null. before I could get the data from API the default null value appears in the page. whereas It is possible in functional component with hooks. likewise how do I re render page in class component.

Comment: You rerender by setting state. But if you're loading data it's completely normal to have a first render where the value is null, both in class components and function components. Your render method may need to check for the possibility of null and return a loading placeholder (or return null). If you'd like more info, please show us the code you currently have.

Answer (score -2):

`this.forceUpdate()`

Put this at the end of your class/method. Should do the trick.

[Source](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-when-to-force-react-component-re-render/#:%7E:text=Forcing%20an%20update%20on%20a%20React%20class%20component&text=In%20any%20user%20or%20system,Virtual%20DOM%20and%20DOM%20state.)

Comment: forceUpdate should almost never be used, and from the description this seems like it just requires state.

Comment: Fair enough. Suggested forceupdate because there's no code provided